# Image registration

Tags: image, registration, sift

any ideas on how to do a simple image registration (I have IMAGE1 and IMAGE2 takes from the same subject, but with camera moving a little and want to match IMAGE2 with IMAGE1)?
I checked MANY softwares to do that, but they're all focused on medical images, so I couldn't input a simple JPEG (one even allowed PGM, but didn't work).

thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612037/comparing-images-using-sift and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500498/how-to-use-sift-algorithm-to-compute-how-similiar-two-images-are

Comment: The best method depends on what specifically you're trying to do.  Provide some more details.  These are camera photos?  How much are the images moving?  Are they rotating?  Zooming in and out?  Are things moving in them?

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent package called "ANTS", which you should refer to:

http://www.picsl.upenn.edu/ANTS/

You may also like to look into a popular package called "ITK":

http://itk.org/

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you need to break it up into managable steps. 
1. You have to have a set of similar points (this is typically found by feature detection) or user selection.
2. Once you have the points needed you need to find the transformation matrix between the two images (based on the given points you recieved). 
3. Use the transformation matrix to translate one image onto another.

Things That Should Help:

1. Feature Detection Algorithms: SIFT
2. Topic that this is under in computer vision: Photo stitching, Homographies, Image Registration

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to perform it on slicer, look at the package: general registration
you can simply insert your images, define your registration type and your transformation file and then run it.

[image: registration in Slicer]

Answer (score 0):

[Simple ITK](https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/index.html), primarily for medical, will read .jpg's and has the full suite of registration tools.

```
reader = sitk.ImageFileReader()
reader.SetImageIO("JPEGimageIO")
reader.SetFileName(inputImageFileName)
image = reader.Execute();
```