# Calculating corresponding pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, correspondence

I have a computer vision set up with two cameras. One of this cameras is a time of flight camera. It gives me the depth of the scene at every pixel. The other camera is standard camera giving me a colour image of the scene.

We would like to use the depth information to remove some areas from the colour image. We plan on object, person and hand tracking in the colour image and want to remove far away background pixel with the help of the time of flight camera. It is not sure yet if the cameras can be aligned in a parallel set up.

We could use OpenCv or Matlab for the calculations.

I read a lot about rectification, Epipolargeometry etc but I still have problems to see the steps I have to take to calculate the correspondence for every pixel.

What approach would you use, which functions can be used. In which steps would you divide the problem? Is there a tutorial or sample code available somewhere?

**Update** We plan on doing an automatic calibration using known markers placed in the scene

Comment: I suppose you have already considered doing the tracking with only the range camera (or with the normal camera)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want robust correspondences, you should consider [SIFT](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/). There are several implementations in MATLAB - I use the [Vedaldi-Fulkerson VL Feat library](http://www.vlfeat.org/).

If you **really** need fast performance (and I think you don't), you should think about using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org)'s [SURF](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/) detector.

If you have any other questions, do ask. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500498/how-to-use-sift-algorithm-to-compute-how-similiar-two-images-are/1501903#1501903) of mine might be useful.

**PS:** By correspondences, I'm assuming you want to find the coordinates of a projection of the same 3D point on both your images - i.e. the coordinates `(i,j)` of a pixel `u_A` in Image A and `u_B` in Image B which is a projection of the same point in 3D.